# A three digit number $a4b$ is divisible by $9$. If we switch the first and last digits we get a number that is bigger by $99$. Find $a4b$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality

I made an equation 
$$(100b+40+a)-(100a+40+b)=99$$ simplified that to $b-a=1$ , but do not know where to go from there.

Comment: Then you need to use the first condition: $100b+40+(b-1)=9k$. Since $101b+39=99b+2b+36+3=9k$, we obtain $2b+3=9$, i.e. $b=3$. Thus $a=2$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $a4b$ is divisible by $9$ , we have $$a+b=5 \text { or } a+b = 14$$

Since by reversing the number, we get a bigger number , we conclude $a\lt b$

All possible values of $a,b$ are:
$$(1,4),(2,3),(5,9)\text{ and }(6,8)$$

By simple trial and error , you can show that $(a,b) = (2,3)$

Hence the number is $243$.

Comment: I think it must be 14 instead of 13, and $(5,9),(6,8),(7,7)$ instead of $(4,9),(5,8),(6,7)$. By the way, if $647$ was divisible by $9$, then it would also be a solution, because $746-647 = 99$.

Comment: @ReinhardMeier thanks for correcting!

Answer (score 0):

You found: $b-a=1$.

$a4b$ is divisible by $9$, so: $a+b=5$ or $14$.

Adding the two equations you get: $2b=6$ or $15$.

Can you finish?